# Best Documentation tools for .Net

Tags: c#, .net

Can anybody suggest me a good documentation tools with easy use GUI for C#

Comment: What kind of documentation, code documentation or end user or help files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should go for [sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) instead.  It is an open source project run by Microsoft.

Comment: Sandcastle looks cinda dead too though.

Answer (score 1):

NDOC is a very good tool and can be eaisly used with GUI.

Comment: i think ndoc is a dead project. i am working on .net 4.0 .

Comment: I wish I could unaccept this answer. NDOC iis so totally outdated and unmaintained it is not even funny. Was retired a long time ago. Sandcastle is the "official" replacement. Anyone goind with NDoc basically invests in code that noone looks at anymore. BAD advice.